# Comparison test modification: If $ a_n \ge |{d_n}| $ for $n \ge N_0$, and if $\sum {d_n}$ diverges, then $\sum {a_n}$ diverges. Is it right?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is actually slight modification of conditions in theorem 3.25 (b) from Rudin. Actual theorem is

> "If $ a_n \ge {d_n} \ge 0 $ for $n \ge N_0$, and if $\sum {d_n}$ diverges, then $\sum {a_n}$ diverges."

So it is right when $d_n$ is between $0$ and $a_n$. What will happen when $d_n$ is between $-a_n$ and $0$?

Comment: If $\sum d_n$ does not converge, then $\sum |d_n|$ diverges to $+\infty$, hence you can apply the actual theorem.

Comment: @Rigel why it will diverge to infinity ?

Comment: It seems right that if $\sum{d_n}$ does not converge, then $\sum{|d_n|}$ also won't converge. As $\sum{|d_n|} \ge |\sum{d_n}|$. But how can we say that it will diverge to infinity ?

Comment: If $\sum |d_n|$ is convergent, then also $\sum d_n$ is (because it is absolutely convergent). So, if $\sum d_n$ does not converge, then also $\sum |d_n|$ does not converge. Being a series with non-negative terms, it must diverge to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** $\sum d_n \le | \sum d_n | \le \sum |d_n| \le \sum a_n$ for $n \ge N_0.$

Comment: Means it is right ?

Comment: I have made an edit. Are you able to get now?

Comment: I think by your hint, we can prove that if $\sum{a_n}$ converges then $\sum{d_n}$ will also converge. Hence, Modification is true. Right ?

Comment: Yup. What you say is the contrapositive statement of the statement in the OP. Since contrapositive statement is true, hence the statement in OP is also true.

Comment: Then why in Rudin only used more specific conditions ?

Comment: Well, I just checked in Rudin. Did you see $3.25 (a)$? The part $(b)$ is implied by part $(a)$ i.e $(a) \implies (b)$. So see $(b)$ as a corollary or an application of $(a)$.